# Remember value across multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input box where you click it and it opens a reveal/modal/popup. These input boxes are dynamic/looped so I can't just pick the id.

```
foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<input type="text" id="Filler[<?=row["$i"]?>" name="PickedPlayer" data-open="exampleModal1" value="<?=$row["Player"]?>">
<?endforeach?>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SendPlayer(str) {
    $( "#Filler" ).val(str);
}
</script>
```

This returns the value of what I do in my modal to the first input on the page. If I start on the 2nd one it also returns it on the first. How can I have it store or remember the specific id across clicks, or just where the first click was.

EDIT: I do NOT want to select all of them. I want to select the second one. The one I clicked.

Comment: ID should be unique. You can use class on elements. Add [mcve].

Comment: I would have jquery add a class to the elements when they are clicked so that they can all be selected through one query

Comment: @Binvention I don't want it to input the value into all of the inputs. Just the one I clicked originally.

Comment: Using the same principle you could have it add a unique class to the one originally clicked. Then if one fits under that category it won't add the class to any additional ones so you get only the first clicked element

Answer (score 0):

You can to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Filler")
```

to select all the elements with the class "Filler"

If you give the same ID to multiple elements it may not select all of them and is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  $("input").on ("click",function  (){
       var original=$(".original");
       If (original.length===0){
             $(this).addClass("original");
       }
  });
```

At that point it will only assign the unique class if it's never been assigned before so you only get the original input. You can then add and remove that class and other unique classes to keep track of your different inputs